# Password Grant Handler Slow query

Tags: sql, sql-server, wso2

we are updating our implementation of the WSO2 5.7.0 of Identity server to the 5.11.0.*.
We are using MSSQL, we are facing a big issue with the slowness of a query in the moment we execute a load test on requesting a Password grant handler.

The query is this one:

```
SELECT DISTINCT UM_USER.UM_USER_ID
FROM UM_USER,
     UM_USER_ATTRIBUTE 
WHERE UM_USER_ATTRIBUTE.UM_USER_ID = UM_USER.UM_ID
  AND UM_ATTR_NAME = 'uid'
  and UM_ATTR_VALUE = 'whatever@something.com'
  AND UM_USER_ATTRIBUTE.UM_PROFILE_ID = 'DEFAULT' 
  AND UM_USER_ATTRIBUTE.UM_TENANT_ID = -1234
  AND UM_USER.UM_TENANT_ID = -1234
  ;
```

The table UM_USER_ATTRIBUTE has more than 45million rows and the UM_USER has 1.7 million.

The server hosting MSSQL has 8 core and 32GB of RAM, nevertheless the CPU fills up to 90% when we start the load tests(only with grant_type=passwrod, the others asses to a 25% with spikes of 40%), useless to say this slows everything down.

[load tests results in 10 minutes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ftpH.png)

We tried to change the query to make it use the explicit inner join, like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT UM_USER.UM_USER_ID
FROM UM_USER
INNER JOIN UM_USER_ATTRIBUTE ON UM_USER.UM_ID = UM_USER_ATTRIBUTE.UM_USER_ID
  AND UM_ATTR_NAME= 'uid'
  and UM_ATTR_VALUE='whatever@something.com'
  AND UM_USER_ATTRIBUTE.UM_PROFILE_ID = 'DEFAULT'
  AND UM_USER_ATTRIBUTE.UM_TENANT_ID = -1234
  AND UM_USER.UM_TENANT_ID = -1234;
```

Nothing changed, same loads and 90% of CPU taken.

Comment: why did you add `java` tag?

Comment: It's might be a really good time to change the old comma,joins to INNER JOINs. It's been 30 years since ansi-92 came out

Answer (score 0):

To improve the query performance by reducing the row scans, you can use following indexes as well.
File location `dbscripts/mysql.sql`

```
CREATE INDEX idx_um_user_attribute_comp
ON UM_USER_ATTRIBUTE (UM_ATTR_NAME, UM_ATTR_VALUE, UM_PROFILE_ID, UM_TENANT_ID, UM_USER_ID);
CREATE INDEX idx_um_user_um_id
ON UM_USER (UM_ID);
```

Apart from Slow query, for performance improvment add the following property to the deployment.toml file, if you are using case-insensitive databases (MySQL / MSSQL).

```
CaseInsensitiveUsername = false
UseCaseSensitiveUsernameForCacheKeys = false
```

Comment: Thank you, on the UM_USER_ATTRIBUTE already has the non clustered index: (UM_ATTR_NAME, UM_ATTR_VALUE), do you think this is not enough?

Comment: SQL Server has to do extra work after using your existing index to filter the rows: it still needs to check UM_PROFILE_ID and UM_TENANT_ID against the rows that were found, and then it needs to look up the corresponding UM_USER_ID for each of those rows in order to perform the join. If the table is large, this can result in a significant amount of additional I/O and CPU time.

Comment: I tried to add the indexes as you suggested, but there is no change in the load tests results, the CPU is still at 90%.

Comment: Does your non-clustered index have any columns in the`INCLUDE`, @SerafinoGio ? An index (normally) is only helpful if it is a covering index. An index that tells you the order of 2 columns, when you need to details from 5 is unlikely to be helpful to the data engine. *Sorting* on all the column, however, may not be of great benefit either, Sachin, as that's a pretty bespoke index and may well not be beneficial to any other queries the OP runs.

Comment: Hi, there are no columns written into the "Included columns" tab of the index.
Little background, this index on the (UM_ATTR_NAME, UM_ATTR_VALUE) has been created with the SQL scripts for the migration sent from WSO2.